# Unable to bind fill-height property in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component inside my template which looks like so:

```
<v-container class="map-layers" fill-height>
```

And in JS code I have a boolean property called `collapsed`:

```
data () {
    return {
        collapsed: false
        ...
    }
}
```

This property is changed to `true` or `false` and triggers animated transition. What i want is to bind `fill-height`property to this `collapsed` property. If collapsed is false, I want to have this:

```
<v-container class="map-layers" fill-height>
```

If `collapsed` is true, I want to have this:

```
<v-container class="map-layers">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to do this to bind your property

```
<v-container class="map-layers" :fill-height="collapsed">
```